# Comparing 2-norm of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Assume we have $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 \\ A_2 \end{bmatrix}$, $A$ is $m \times n$ matrix and $A_1$ is non-singular matrix of size $n$ and 
$$ u = Sup {\{\frac{||y||_2}{||Ay||_2} \quad s.t.\quad  y \in C^{n} \quad with \quad y \neq 0}\} $$ 
$$ v = Sup {\{\frac{||z||_2}{||A_{1}z||_2} \quad s.t.\quad  z \in C^{n} \quad with \quad z \neq 0}\} $$ 
Is it correct to assume $u \leq v$?

I would like to verify whether or not my assumption is right.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This follows from the fact that $\|Ay\| = \sqrt{\|A_1y\|^2+\|A_2y\|^2} \ge \|A_1y\|$ for all $y$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was not sure since $z$ and $y$ are not necessarily equal.

Comment: Let's call the two internal expressions $f(y)$ and $g(z)$. You're right that $\sup f(y)$ and $\sup g(z)$ may be attained at different points $y^*$ and $z^*$. However we know that $f(y) \le g(y)$ for all $y$, so in particular $\sup f(y) = f(y^*) \le g(y^*) \le \sup g(y)$. (The argument is a bit more subtle if the suprema are not actually attained, but that is too long for a comment.)